# Transfer OneSignal from existing app to Flutter app

Tags: flutter, push-notification, migration, onesignal

I need to transfer an existing in-production native iOS/Android OneSignal setup to a currently in-dev Flutter app.

I've read through the docs here:

- https://pub.dev/packages/onesignal_flutter
- https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/flutter-sdk-setup

I am concerned that I'll break the production app's notifications in the process (e.g. accidentally invalidating the certificate or something), so want to make sure I don't do something dumb.

Is there a straightforward way of doing this migration?

Any advice/concrete steps would be appreciated.

Thanks.